# Why does my test pass, even though it doesn't meet my logic gate?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm working on telephone validator on FCC.  For some reason this passes `5555555555`. Why does my logic gate pass this number?  For context, this isn't my first attempt at this code.  I've added multiple statements, nested if statements, and it still doesn't catch it. Why does this evaluate to true? Here's the code:

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  if(str[0] === '1' || '(' && str.length >= 10) {
  return true;

  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

telephoneCheck("5555555555");
```

Comment: `|| '('` doesn't make any sense. Non-empty strings are always truthy.

Comment: You need to restate the condition every time you want to check against multiple values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to restate the condition you're comparing (`|| '('` will always be true):

```
if(str[0] === '1' || str[0] === '(' && str.length >= 10) {
```

This is due to the fact that `&&` has a greater precedence than the `||` operator. So without the parenthesis, the `'(' && str.length >= 10` part of the expression is evaluated first. So the ultimate condition becomes `str[0] === '1' || true` which would always be true. So your code would return true for any string of length >= 10

Comment: Thanks, I'll be accepting your answer.  This clears things up a lot, and i'll be sure to keep it in mind for the future.